# Interactive Python sample redirect URL?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-ad-msal

Im trying to follow the Python sample for interactive..its not clear what I put for the redirect URL in the Azure AD app registration.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF! Your question is really unclear- please try and elaborate enough for us to sufficiently help you

Comment: Im trying to get this-> https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/interactive_sample.py to work..but when I run it it says "AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '98404b9f-d167-41f1-85d9-8dd5ae4d406e'."

what do I put in the azure AD app registration for the reply URL?

Answer (score -1):

When you create a new Application in Microsoft Identity Platform you shall see an option for Redirect URI (optional) section. In that section, select Web in the combo-box and enter redirect url you want. For eg: http://localhost:5000/getAToken.

Here your REDIRECT_PATH is `/getAToken`, which shall be included in app config.
Hope this helps !